# Access original unmodified user text in custom directive

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'd like to use a custom directive to wrap certain table cells in a preformatted block.

For example, suppose I want to write documentation for my exciting new calculator:

```
.. Calculator-Operations:: sign examples

You'll love how great this awesome calculator is. 
Check out these exciting innovations!

=========       ==========
you type        result
=========       ==========
+ 1             1
- 1             -1
* 1             ERROR!
/ 1             ERROR!
```

I can retrieve each table cell node in my directive's implementation, but the node has already been processed by Sphinx (of course), so the first three cells are treated as bulleted lists.

I'd like the generated document to behave as if I had surrounded each "you type" cell with double backticks. I could accomplish this if I could retrieve the raw text of the node or if I could prevent Sphinx from transforming this particular node. (I could also accomplish this by parsing the entire block's content myself, but that sounds unpleasant.)

What is the best way of transforming the original, untransformed user input in these cells?